# Looking for a Document Editor based on HTML with Headings folding or a Nagivation Outline Sidebar

Tags: windows, html-editor, wysiwyg

- Looking a Windows stand-alone app (if it runs on Linux that fine too :)
  Commercial products are OK.
- I have been using FrontPage 2003 to this date
- I compose tons of pages locally as logs/notes
- I will not upload these pages to the web
- My pages do not include Javascript (scripting)

Before you read further:

1. I have been using FrontPage2003 to create hyperlinked notes/logs that are **stored** as "clean/not bloated" HTML.
2. I know about HTML tags but it's not something I want to look at when I am logging issues and thoughts as Text/Images.
3. I want to look at rendered HTML at all times. My logs are organized as One-level peer directories like below per project.

[image]

What features I currently have/use:

1. WYSIWYG editing (keyboard shortcuts to assign heading 1,2,3,4, numbered-list)
2. Drag and Drop of links from the browser history bar or address field.
3. Pasting of clipboard images or HTML
4. Tabbed interface to quickly select which file I want to edit (I could live with a large popup list of currently opened files to select from).
5. I do (local) hyperlinking of my pages
6. I do use some CSS.  Most of my pages have the same template inline (AKA: style sheet inside the head/head tags) some use a shared external style sheet.

**What feature I want to get:**

1. Folding (AKA collapsing) of headings inside the editor not necessarily when viewed in a browser I seldom use the later. IOW, I am looking for an editor feature to fold to headings only, and NOT JavaScript to fold when viewing in a browser.
2. Alternatively to folding the headings a sidebar with an outline of all the headings would assist in seeing the forest from the trees.
3. Mouse-wheel zoom would be a plus :)

I searched and I searched but Many reviews talk about Atom, Notepad++, coffecup, brackets, ... which all seem about coding (JS etc...) rather then composing text WYSIWYG. I seldom drop into the HTML code.

I have MSWord2010 and could move to 2013, but I am not sure I can trust it for my HTML to Microsoft. In the past it did weird things to stored HTML.
I do like the fact it has a Navigation Pane as shown in the snapshot below. You can double click the outline and it will jump to the corresponding heading.

Thank you, your insights much appreciated.

[image]

About MSWord, if I load a copy of an INDEX.HTM into Word and fake-edit (Ctrl-K) a single link, for example. Word will injects all kinds of **garbage**, see this file compare below. The HTML on the left is Word saved after a single small edit. It spews and injects tons of weird styles... **NO WAY JOSE, I WON'T LET THAT HAPPEN**

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! From the context I assume it should work on Windows (as all the programs you've mentioned are Windows progs), that correct? As all mentioned products are paid software I further assume you're willing to spend some money if needed. What would be the limit you've set for that? And are subscription fees OK, or only one-time payment?

Comment: Most of your assumptions are correct. I am stuck in Windows and for example many CAD programmers are designed for Windows/Mac alone, probably for good reasons $$$. I am in the process of moving my Windows hosting to Linux butting against the case sensitivity of Linux, I am strongly against anything case sensitive :) including programming languages. If you have some commercial software in mind please suggest I will certainly look into them.

Comment: Sorry, but all that I have in mind is improving your question so you can get answers really matching your needs. I don't use wysiwyg HTML editors but prefer to keep my HTML code slim (hence using a plain-text editor). So maybe you could [edit] your question with the missing details?